# Unexpected behaviour of function findpeaks in MATLAB's Signal Processing Toolbox

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Edit: Actually this is not unexpected behaviour, but I still need a solution. 
`findpeaks compares each element of data to its neighboring values.`

I have data which contains peaks which I detect with the function [findpeaks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/findpeaks.html) from the Signal Processing Toolbox. Sometimes the function seems not to detect the peaks properly, when I have the same value twice next to each other. This occurs very rarly in my data, but here is a sample to illustrate my problem:

```
>> values

values =

   -0.0324
   -0.0371
   -0.0393
   -0.0387
   -0.0331
   -0.0280
   -0.0216
   -0.0134
   -0.0011
    0.0098
    0.0217
    0.0352
    0.0467
    0.0548
    0.0639
    0.0740
    0.0813
    0.0858                  <-- here should be another peak
    0.0858                  <--
    0.0812
    0.0719
    0.0600
    0.0473
    0.0353
    0.0239
    0.0151
    0.0083
    0.0034
   -0.0001
   -0.0025
   -0.0043
   -0.0057
   -0.0048
   -0.0038
   -0.0026
    0.0007
    0.0043
    0.0062
    0.0083
    0.0106
    0.0111
    0.0116
    0.0102
    0.0089
    0.0057
    0.0025
   -0.0025
   -0.0056
```

Now the findpeaks function only finds one peak:

```
>> [pks loc] = findpeaks(values)

pks =

    0.0116


loc =

    42
```

If I plot the data, it becomes obvious that findpeaks misses one of the peaks at the location `18/19` because they both have the value `0.08579`.

[image]

What is the best way to find those missing peaks?

Comment: try the following resources: http://www.billauer.co.il/peakdet.html , http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/PeakFindingandMeasurement.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image processing toolbox, you can  use [IMREGIONALMAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imregionalmax.html) to find the peaks, after which you can use regionprops to find the center of the regions (if that's what you need), i.e.

```
bw = imregionalmax(signal);
peakLocations = find(bw); %# returns n peaks for an n-tuple of max-values

stats = regionprops(bw,'Centroid');
peakLocations = cat(1,stats.Centroid); %# returns the center of the n-tuple of max-values
```

Comment: The problem wasn't that I only detected one peak, but that I didn't detect the high peak at all.

Comment: @Lucas: Yes, that wasn't formulated very well, and the filtering solution is not guaranteed to fix the problem, so I've removed it. Anyway, `imregionalmax` does what you want, except it also works if there are more than 2 equal values. You still might want to filter first to remove local maxima that are due to noise.

Comment: imregionalmax does indeed seem to work. I still probably use my own function.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old topic, but maybe some are still looking for an easier solution to this (like I did today):

You could also just substract some very small fixed value from all values on a plateau, except from the first value. This causes each first value on a plateau to always be the highest on the respective plateaus, causing them to be included as peaks.

Just make something like this part of your code:

```
peaks = yourdata;
verysmallvalue = .001;
plateauvalue = peaks(1);

for i = 2:size(peaks,1)
    if peaks(i) == plateauvalue
        peaks(i) = peaks(i) - verysmallvalue;
    else
        plateauvalue = peaks(i);
    end
end

[PKS,LOCS] = findpeaks(peaks);
plot(yourdata);
hold on;
plot(LOCS, yourdata(LOCS), 'Color', 'Red', 'Line', 'None', 'Marker', 'o');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [second derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test) instead?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own simpler version of findpeaks, which seems to work for my purpose.

```
function [pks,locs] = my_findpeaks(X)      
    M = numel(X);
    pks = [];
    locs = [];
    if (M < 4)
        datamsgid = generatemsgid('emptyDataSet');
        error(datamsgid,'Data set must contain at least 4 samples.');
    else
        for idx=1:M-3
            if X(idx)< X(idx+1) && X(idx+1)>=X(idx+2) && X(idx+2)> X(idx+3)
                pks = [pks X(idx)];
                locs = [locs idx];
            end

        end

    end
end
```

Edit: To clarify, the problem arose, when I had a peak which was exactly between two sample points and those two sample points had coincidentally the same value. It only happend a couple of times in more than 10.000 cases.

Comment: I cannot see how `X(idx+1)> X(idx+1)` ever evaluates to true. There must be a typo somewhere.

Comment: @Jonas: Yeah, sorry you are right. I took an older version, because I added some things that where specific to my problem. And it contained the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you describe is a known bug in versions of MATLAB prior to R2010b. The minimum example is

```
findpeaks([0 1 1 0])
```

which returns `[]`, while

```
findpeaks([0 1 0])
```

returns the (position of the) peak.

The bug has been fixed in R2010b and later, see the official [Bug Report](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/details/605368). With that fix, `findpeaks` returns the rising edge of "peaks with repeated values" (which I would call *plateaus*).